# Efficient way to check if column has all certain values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am using following query to show only those inspectors who have got both qualifications.

```
      DECLARE @CertType QualificationType;  --2,3  

      select i.InspectorID from Inspectors i  
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT _id.InspectorID
            FROM InspectorDocs _id 
            WHERE _id.QualificationTypeID IN (select [QualificationTypeID] from @CertType) GROUP BY _id.InspectorID
            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT _id.QualificationTypeID) = (select count(*) from @CertType)
            ) as id on id.inspectorid = i.inspectorid
```

Is there any better way to find if column has all given values?

**Schema**

Inspectors: Inspectors (PK)

InspectorDocs : DocID (PK) , InspectorID (FK), QualificationTypeID (FK)

QualificationTypE : QualificationTypeID (PK)

Comment: Provide schema and data sample.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken what you're doing is what's known as a relational division, and another (slightly non-intuitive) way to express this is the following query, which should give better performance:

```
select * from Inspectors i 
where not exists (
    select * from QualificationType c
    where QualificationTypeID IN (2,3) 
    and not exists (
       select * from InspectorDocs id
       where c.QualificationTypeID = id.QualificationTypeID
       and id.InspectorID = i.InspectorID))
```

If you want to dig deeper into this subject I recommend reading [Divided We Stand: The SQL of Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) by Joe Celko.